# Connection reset after large text submission in WAMP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, apache, wamp

I have a PHP program that receives a list of items (1 to x) and compares them to the inventory then prints out a report. It works up to 1161 items, after that a `connection reset` is thrown.

I need this to be able to process up to 5000 lines. The line items are up to 10 alpha-numeric characters per line. A file with 3462 lines (69 kb) is killing it...

I have checked many of Apache and PHP's settings, but can't figure it out yet.

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 3000);
set_time_limit(360);
```

There is a lot of old code and the full file works in pieces, so no bad data is getting in. Any ideas?

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with your code

Comment: Have you tried disabling xdebug?

Answer (score 0):

it might be a limit in the parameters transmission. Are you using GET or POST to submit? If using GET, a URL is limited in its maximum length. The limit depends on OS and Apache version etc.

If using POST, there might be some limits, too.

Volker

Answer (score 0):

Dr Dan was right, it was old code that I had inherited and patched a few times. *The problem was a threading issue*, to many calls to a function. Completely rewrote in OOPs style and it is working fine